# Any chance of getting the gazebo2 and the collada-dom packages added to the armhf archive?

Tags: ros, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gazebo2 and collada-dom can't be found in any of the ubuntu repositories and are typically found in the ros repo for other architectures. These will be useful for bootstrapping any of the armhf full builds.

PCL and sbcl are also missing, but I can build these in a PPA.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173857/any-chance-of-getting-the-gazebo2-and-the-collada-dom-packages-added-to-the-armhf-archive?/) by [jolting](https://answers.ros.org/users/18899/jolting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have collada-dom-dev builds for most of the Ubuntu armhf variants, and PCL builds for 12.04 and 13.04. Which ones are you missing?

I haven't tried to build gazebo... it doesn't really make sense to try to run gazebo on a low-powered ARM cpu, and I don't want to spend time on something that won't be useful. (The same line of reasoning goes for rviz).

If you can manage to do builds of SBCL for armhf, you will be my hero.

**EDIT**

I've added builds of collada-dom-dev and pcl to my repository. I'm currently working on full builds of ROS.
I also have a build of SBCL in the works. Fingers crossed.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jolting](https://answers.ros.org/users/18899/jolting/) on 2014-06-18**:
BeagleBone Black supports 14.04.
Some of those arm processors aren't that low powered. For example the exynos processors have 8 cores and nvidia has a board with cuda built in.

I'm trying to figure out how adam conrad bootstraped sbcl for ppc. Then I'll have a ppa with sbcl.